# Multi Term Match in elastic search not work for boolean filter

Tags: java, elasticsearch

i have multiple fields  want to query on it .

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder =  QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(text, "nameAr", "nameEn", "authorType", "active")
    .type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.BEST_FIELDS);
```

it works for all fields but not work for "active" as it is boolean .. how to do ?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: no error  .. but when i try to search with "true" didn't return any data